# Regulation of the replication of mtDNA at embryonic level

Tags: molecular-genetics, genomics, embryology

While reading an article on mitochondrial inheritance I came across [this link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/humupd/dmq002).

The results state that mitochondrial DNA replication is regulated in different cells of an embryo at different levels. How is this regulated?

Comment: I'm sorry for not having mentioned the key word GENOMIC earlier. That made the question unclear, as I understand.

Comment: As for the synchrony of mitochondrial and cellular division it would be of a great help to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a topic which seems to be not very clear yet. References say that this is obviously dependent on the tissue and the "gene dosage" seems to play a role, and that this is probably regulated by a yet unknown factor (see "[Mitochondrial DNA replication: what we know.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12880201)" and "[Replication and transcription of mammalian mitochondrial DNA.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12525854)").
Newer articles suggest that it depends also on the transcription of the mtDNA (see "[The interface of transcription and DNA replication in the mitochondria.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22207204)" and "[Mitochondrial transcription factor A regulates mitochondrial transcription initiation, DNA packaging, and genome copy number.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22465614)"). I will see, if there are other interesting publications, if there are problems with accessing these articles, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Mitochondria divide by binary fission. The regulation of this division differs between eukaryotes. In many single-celled eukaryotes, their growth and division is linked to the cell cycle.

Comment: I guess the concern of the asker is to understand the type of regulation and not whether it is regulated. Can you please elaborate on the mechanism of this synchrony between mitochondrial division and cell cycle.